# Web crawler unable to get links off https://steemit.com/trending

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

when I run the main file of my crawler I get this 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte. I would post code but its a large program and I am unsure where or what the problem is. The site is hardcore encrypted could this be the problem?

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: why is that Im very clear and I have read that?

Comment: If I knew where the error was i would post it just wanted to see what some one else thinks.

Comment: I think where boardrider is coming from is that its good to post your code. Otherwise it's hard to know whats going wrong and how to rectify that. You don't need to post your whole program, just the offending line of code and any other lines that you think will help. On topic, that is an encoding issue and we'll need to know the string that you're decoding. Is that the website itself?

Comment: The problem with the question is that without at least basic knowledge of how your scraper works it's impossible to judge what the problem might be... Is the problem coming from the site source? Is it coming from the way you read it? Is it coming from some included library? is it coming from the way you manipulate the data?

Comment: i understand my bad was not sure what code to put tho and if it would be a bad thing to post a lot of code

Comment: Ill edit it latter with the code I think would be helpfull thanks

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, an example would be of immense help.

But if I had to take an educated stab in the dark... the specific problem you have is that the page you are scraping probably has some unicode characters that can't be stored without being encoded. So... try encoding the data as follows...

```
item['title'] = however_you_got_title.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: ill give it a shot